# How to use object binding in Maui?

Tags: maui

I have the following objects in C#:

Object A:

```
    [ObservableObject]
    public partial class MyClassA
    {
        
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool isSelected;

        public MyClassA(bool IsSelected)
        {       
            this.isSelected = IsSelected;
        }
    }
```

Object B:

Object B references object A in a ObservableCollection:

```
    [ObservableObject]
    public partial class MyClassB
        {        
            [ObservableProperty]        
            ObservableCollection<MyClassA> myClassAList;
            
            public MyClassB(ObservableCollection<MyClassA> MyClassAList)
            {
                this.myClassAList = MyClassAList;            
            }
            
            public override string ToString()
            {
                int c = 0;
                for (i=0; i<= myClassAList.count-1; i++) {
                    if (myClassAList(i).IsSelected) {
                        c = c + 1;
                    }
                }
                return "Items selected " + c;
            }
        }
```

What I need is whenever something changes in any object in the list myClassAList, **MyClassB.ToString** also should notify the change.

So far when binding a single MyClassA object to a XAML page, changes are reflected on the use interface (this is OK).

However when binding a MyClassB object, changes in the list of objects MyClassA, are not reflected (this is not OK).

How can I solve this?

Comment: are you expecting B's `ToString()` to update automatically when A changes?

Comment: @Jason yes exactly. Is that possible please ?

Comment: No.  I believe I pointed this out in a previous question of yours.  If you want that sort of behavior you need to create a `Description` property in B that subscribes to the `PropertyChanged` events in A.  There may be some dependency attributes available that make this simpler.  This really has nothing to do with MAUI, it's a basic C#/MVVM class design issue.